# Classification trees: the best Predictor and the ability to predict

Tags: prediction, cart

The topmost decision node, the root node in a classification tree is said to be the best predictor of the model. Does this mean the root node variable is also the best in predicting the target variable?

Comment: Yes, it is the strongest predictor, by default. But you may force any (not the strongest) predictor to define the root 1. Most implementations allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes, but you should avoid drawing conclusions from a single tree. Trees have low bias, but high variance, meaning that the addition or removal of a few observations only from your training set can change the first split, and modify the entire tree structure in a cascading fashion. On the other hand, ensemble methods such as Random Forests and Stochastic Gradient Boosting allow more variables to play an important role in determining tree structure (by considering only a random subset of predictors as candidates at each split), and by combining the output from many trees, they generate way more reliable variable importance measures. I would advise reading the [Hastie](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf) for more details.